# understanding this "git bare repo" approach to dotfiles

Tags: git

[**I found this neat way to migrate dotfiles between computers.**](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/)

It works, but I don't really understand how. I can do everything he mentions in the article, but what I can't figure out is how I fetch and update after making a change on another device. I usually just do a `git fetch --all` + `git reset --hard origin/branch`. This isn't doing the trick, so I'm updating by deleting the .cfg folder and all the tracked dotfiles, then re-applying the installation procedures. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: to be clear, are you running `config fetch --all` + `config reset --hard origin/branch` ?

Comment: No, that gives me error messages. Those commands are what I normally use when updating a local repo from a remote, but in this case that does not update the dotfiles in my ~/ directory.

Comment: At a guess, the problem is you normally rely on the initial `git clone` to set up "remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository".  But `--bare` is documented as skipping that, so I'm a bit confused by the blog!  Looking at the HN thread, maybe it would be better with `git clone --no-checkout --separate-git-dir=~/.cfg  <git-repo-url> ~`

Comment: i mean of course the `git` command doesn't work on it's own, there is no `.git` directory :)

Comment: If you read the comments below the blog, people already noticed the instructions are broken because of this: `config push` can't possibly work as suggested.  If you look a bit further, people end up working around the instructions, getting it to work after a manual `remote add <name> <url>` (presumably `config remote ...` would work).

Comment: As an aside I would encourage you to graduate from constant use of `git reset --hard`.  It's a bit dangerous IMO, silently throwing away any uncommitted changes.  I think `git reset --keep` will preserve any uncommitted changes, aborting if there's a conflict.